# Using GWT to build a sortable table/grid without EXT/GXT/Smart GWT/etc

Tags: sorting, gwt

For some background, I'm currently an intern who has been asked to use GWT to create some kind of table/grid that can be sorted by column. Ideally my boss (who told me to ask for help about this here on Stack Overflow) also wants to be able to have multiple pages of data as well, but I'm concentrating on the sorting part right now.

Before jumping to suggest the various EXT and GXT things, unfortunately 1) what this will be used for will eventually be a part of their product, and therefore, used commercially and 2) this is for a not-for-profit company, so they don't really want to pay for a license. I have been searching for what feels like weeks in vain for something that I can both use and understand.

I am using Eclipse (indigo) to create GWT web apps, but I am still quite a newbie at anything related to GWT and I'm sure that most of my problem is that I don't really understand how to get and use the code that is presented as an example in tutorials. I have read through all the GWT documentation I can find and many tutorials and showcases, but I still don't really understand how to do things... which is unfortunate and frustrating. I have also tried using the GWT Designer in Eclipse and while neat, I can't use the CellTable stuff (which of course is exactly what my boss wants) - I assume because I don't have the license for it? Right now, I don't need to be getting data from a server (literally, if I could just put all my people-data in an ArrayList and populate columns from there, I would be very happy).

Can anyone help me out with this? Sorry it's kind of a two-fold question (one that I'm such a newbie about GWT, two that I am not having any luck figuring out how to make a sortable table/grid) but I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

CellTable is one of the more complicated concepts in GWT. You are looking in the right place, the documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideUiCellTable.

This should have everything you need including all the code with an EntryPoint class. I think it is just a case of getting this code running on your machine and working through it line by line understanding what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have looked through this several times to try to understand what's going on. My big problem is that I keep getting an onModuleLoad() threw an exception error when I try to run it in hosted mode. I literally just tried copying some of Google's code over, and it looks like it ought to work...but doesn't. Thank you for your advice!